# Kotlin Обход многомерного объекта

Tags: kotlin

```
var obj1 = object {
    var name = "object"
    var type = "object"
    var props = object {
        var prop1 = "123"
        var prop2 = "abc2"
        var prop3 = object {
            var type = "object3"
            var prop4 = "abc4"
        }
    }
}
```

Еcть ли способ в Kotlin  рекурсивно обойти такой объект?

Comment: только через рефлексию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключите в ваш проект библиотеку `kotlin-reflect`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:(версия котлин)")
}
```

Рекурсивно распечатать все строковые поля для предложенного объекта можно с помощью следующей функции:

```
fun printProperties(instance: Any) {
    for (property in (instance::class as KClass<Any>).memberProperties) {
        val name = property.name
        val value = property.get(instance)
        when (property.returnType) {
            String::class.createType() -> println("$name => $value")
            else -> printProperties(value)
        }
    }
}
```